# Account IDs not working for Horizon Testnet API

Tags: horizon

I am testing the Accounts endpoint on the Horizon testnet API. On [this documentation page](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/accounts-single.html), there is the sample address:

```
GA2HGBJIJKI6O4XEM7CZWY5PS6GKSXL6D34ERAJYQSPYA6X6AI7HYW36
```

Which when plugged into the example [here](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=accounts&endpoint=single&values=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiR0EySEdCSklKS0k2TzRYRU03Q1pXWTVQUzZHS1NYTDZEMzRFUkFKWVFTUFlBNlg2QUk3SFlXMzYifQ%3D%3D&network=test) I get this error message:

```
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/not_found",
  "title": "Resource Missing",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "The resource at the url requested was not found.  This is usually occurs for one of two reasons:  The url requested is not valid, or no data in our database could be found with the parameters provided."
}
```

My personal address doesn't work either. [But some account IDs do work](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=accounts&endpoint=single&values=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiR0FJM0dKMlEzQjM1QU9aSjM2QzRBTkUzSFNTNE5LN1dJNkROTzRaU0hSQVg2Tkc3Qk1YNlZKRVIifQ%3D%3D&network=test) (in this example, the donation address at the bottom of StellarChain.io.

All of these addresses exist and work just fine on StellarChain.io. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oliver mentioned, testnet & public are separated.

The key is valid for both net, but some are "created" (funded) only at one of the two for the moment.

I just funded it at testnet, so you can get a proper response with this key now. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ah, some accounts exist on public and not on the testnet api.